# Angular Filter Dates (Past / Future) with Moment.js

Tags: angularjs, time, momentjs, angularjs-filter

Say I have JSON data with objects like so:

```
$scope.events = [
    {
        title: 'Event 1',
        date: '2015-04-11 10:00'
    },
    ...
];
```

And I display it using `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

How would I create a filter to only show future events and hide past ones (compare event.date to the current time)? Normally I would use [Moment's .isBefore()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).

---

**UPDATE:**

I'd like the name of the `date` property to be configurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You should define a custom filter using Moment's `isAfter` method.
An example can be found on http://onehungrymind.com/build-custom-filter-angularjs-moment-js/

Their definition of the filter, they've even made the cutoff date configurable:

```
.filter('isAfter', function() {
  return function(items, dateAfter) {
    // Using ES6 filter method
    return items.filter(function(item){
      return moment(item.date).isAfter(dateAfter);
    })
  }
})
```

Or if you don't want to make that configurable:

```
.filter('isFuture', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.filter(function(item){
      return moment(item.date).isAfter(new Date());
    })
  }
})
```

To apply it:

```
ng-repeat="event in events | isAfter:date"
```

or

```
ng-repeat="event in events | isFuture"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You'd like to make the name of the date property configurable. You can do that. The trick in calling it is that `item.date` is the same as `item['date']`.
Second trick is that you can provide a default value for a parameter by using `||`. `param || 'default'` will use the param value if it is provided, and `'default'` if it is undefined.

So

```
.filter('isFuture', function() {
  return function(items, dateFieldName) {
    return items.filter(function(item){
      return moment(item[dateFieldName || 'date']).isAfter(new Date());
    })
  }
})
```

Then in the ng-repeat you get for the default:

```
ng-repeat="event in events | isFuture"
```

or to specify the field name:

```
ng-repeat="event in events | isFuture:'deadline'"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to generalize the filter so you could specify the name of the date key? For example, say each object has  `date: '2015-04-11 10:00'` and  `deadline: '2015-04-12 10:00'` attributes and you want to be able to filter on both to apply some classes. Is that possible or would you have to create an additional (practically identical) filter?

Comment: @dougmacklin you can use one filter for both, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks @flup! i have one related follow up question that might be better answered in chat, would you mind checking it out? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74862/angular-date-filter

Answer (score 1):

even simpler, in your controller:

```
$scope.now = moment().format(); //normalised format (ISO 8601)
```

in your view

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">
        <span ng-if="event.date > now">{{event.title}}<span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just normalise your event.date with the "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601) format, you can use `moment().format()` as well